# React Router only rendering first 2 components

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Banner from './Banner';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Services from './Services';
import Book from './Book';

function Layout() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Header/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/About" components={About}/>
                <Route exact path="/Services" components={Services}/>
                <Route exact path="/Book" components={Book}/>
            <Footer/>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

Only the "/" and "/Home" paths are rendering when clicking the links. If I set the "/" component to any of the other ones (About, Services, Book) then they render correctly. Really confusing :/

Comment: What happens whenother components are loaded? Is it a blank page?

Comment: The header and footer components load but nothing in between. So blank page yes.

Comment: spelling mistake perhaps: `component` not `components`